# How to make a dictionary with the values as a set?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary, but I want the values part of it to be a set. I would like to be putting these values in a set every time I loop through For example,
{key : value} -> {key : value, value, value}, {key : value, value} Below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

def linkTexts(url):
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
    
    q2Dictionary = {}
    links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
    for link in links:
        linkUrl = link["href"]
        if 'http' in linkUrl:
            linkText = link.get_text().strip()
            if linkUrl not in q2Dictionary.keys():
                q2Dictionary[linkUrl] = linkText
            if linkUrl in q2Dictionary.keys():
                q2Dictionary.update({linkUrl: linkText})
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: It's worth noting that `dict.update()` is a bit overkill here when you could just use `q2Dictionary[linkUrl] = linkText`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) with an empty set:

```
q2Dictionary.setdefault(linkUrl, set()).add(linkText)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if linkUrl not in q2Dictionary:
    q2Dictionary[linkUrl] = set()
q2Dictionary[linkUrl].add(linkText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a dictionary of strings. Why not make a dictionary of string lists?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
def linkTexts(url):
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
    
    q2Dictionary = {}
    links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
    for link in links:
        linkUrl = link["href"]
        if 'http' in linkUrl:
            linkText = link.get_text().strip()
            if linkUrl not in q2Dictionary.keys():
                q2Dictionary[linkUrl] = [linkText]
            else:
                q2Dictionary[linkUrl].append(linkText)
```

Initialize each key with the linkText as a list by its own and append linkText that has the same key to the existing list.

Comment: This will append the first `linkText` twice because the key `linkUrl` exists once the second `if` is executed. Instead of using `if linkUrl in q2Dictionary.keys()`, you could simply use `else`, or better yet, rewrite to use `q2Dictionary.setdeault()` like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66020360/4518341).

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [answer] if you want tips.

Comment: Thanks! Modified based on @wjandrea comment